# Adding Constraint to Paragraph field

Tags: forms, paragraphs

I have a Content Type with a field that references 6 different paragraph types.  The field is set up to accept unlimited values.   For one of the types I would like to have exactly four values added.  I've been trying to add a Constraint but it seems that Constraints are built to check if a fields values are valid and not if there are only four items

Is using hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter the correct hook or should I be focused on using hook_entity_type_alter or maybe even some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter` and when you add a constraint to the field (and not to a item or property), your constraint gets the entire field item list, so you can check how many items you have of which type, see [FieldConfigInterface::addConstraint](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigInterface.php/function/FieldConfigInterface%3A%3AaddConstraint/8.7.x):

```
function mymodule_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node' && $bundle == 'page') {
    $fields['field_paragraph']->addConstraint('MymoduleParagraphTypes');
  }
}
```

Example for a constraint restricting the field to four paragraph items of a specific type:

```
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
    $paragraphs = array_filter($items->referencedEntities(), function ($paragraph) {
      return $paragraph->bundle() === 'image';
    });
    if (!empty($paragraphs) && count($paragraphs) != 4) {
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->errorMessage);
    }
  }
```

You can generate the constraint with the Drush command:

```
drush generate plugin-constraint
```

---

Edit:
If you need to check field values inside of the paragraphs then use $item->entity. See [How to validate a paragraph field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308364/how-to-validate-a-paragraph-field)

Comment: This seems like what I want.  I keep getting plugin Instance class does not exist though.

Comment: Try the drush generate command. In this example the constraint ID was `MymoduleParagraphTypes`, which you find in the first class generated. Then put the example code in the second class.

Comment: Starting fresh got the weird errors to go away. Marked your answer.  Counting is a bit off though. I want four and it is only finding ine

Comment: It seems like the code is only counting the number of paragraphs on the edit page and not the number of entities in that paragraph. If I do count ($items->$referencedEntities()) it always returns one no matter how many I've added

Comment: I've tested this on a field accepting different paragraphs types and it worked. I had to add exactly four Image paragraphs once I've started to add an Image paragraph. Therefor the empty condition, so you could use the field for the other types without adding images.

Comment: Ahhh I think my question wasn't clear.  For a specific paragraph type I want to require that four entities are added. How can I count each referenced entity in that one paragraph

Comment: OK. this is a different question, adding a constraint to an entity reference field, which is in your case inside of a paragraph entity. So you can use the same hook, but check for the entity type id `paragraph` and for the paragraph type as bundle. Then the constraint gets a list of referenced entities (not paragraphs).

Comment: So I've changed entity type id to paragraph. And the bundle to the paragraph type.  The constraint though returns an empty array. In the hook what should I be using to the left of addConstraint? It was the field in the content type but that is Null now.

Comment: You are no longer in the content type you've mentioned in the question. Now you have to choose a field name of an entity reference field you have added to the paragraph type.